# React - issues with loading an external script

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Working on my first React project and kinda new to JS, I am struggling with a very basic issue. I wonder what is the best practice to debug this?

I did create my app with `create-react-app` and I don't succeed loading an external script. Surprisingly I didn't find any help online or in the doc so far, rather any mention of this being an issue.

At the bottom of `public/index.html`, if I write:

```
<script>
  console.log('Hello World!');
</script>
```

=> the console display `'Hello World!'`, normal, all good!

But if instead I do:

```
<script type="text/babel" src="../src/js/helloworld.js"></script>
```

and the `helloworld.js` file just contains `console.log('Hello World!');`

=> the console doesn't display anything!

Apparently, `type` must be "`text/babel"` or I get a syntax error.

What am I doing wrong ?

My folder structure is:

```
my-app
├── README.md
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── .gitignore
├── public
│   └── favicon.ico
│   └── index.html
│   └── manifest.json
└── src
    └── App.css
    └── App.js
    └── App.test.js
    └── index.css
    └── index.js
    └── logo.svg
    └── js
        └── helloworld.js
```

Comment: It might seem a little more complicated with create-react-app. See that post: [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3007)

Comment: did you import helloworld.js into index.js?

Comment: No I didn’t. It seems I have to import it as a node module so I am going to look into that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The boilerplate (create-react-app) you used to create your project utilizes the node.js development environment, so you should stick to that development workflow - by creating node modules.

So you need to convert helloworld.js to a node module:

```
exports.helloWorld = function() {
    console.log('Hello World!');
};
```

Then use it in other modules of your application (i.e. index.js):

```
import { helloWorld } from './js/helloWorld';

helloWorld(); // or call from within a React.js component
```

You should read about how node.js modules work.

Comment: Thank you, that’s a great explanation. I am going to read more on node.js modules

Answer (score 4):

You could also make it work if you move your `helloworld.js` file inside of the `public` folder, as the server using by `create-react-app` serves all the assets in the `public` folder but does not serve `src`. [Here is the documentation](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#when-to-use-the-public-folder)

in your `index.html`

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/helloworld.js"></script>
```

in your project put the `js` folder inside of public `public/js/helloworld.js`

The type should be `text/javascript` as it let your browser know how to interpret the file. The syntax error, you are getting is due to the fact that `create-react-app` renders the index.html if the file is not found, and then your browser sees html instead of javascript, hence the error : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Also `create-react-app` hides a lot of complexity for you and it is going to be difficult to understand all of what happens behind the scene. If you want to go through the complete tooling system in place you could run `npm run eject` (but read the [docs](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-eject) first :) as it can't be reversed.

Comment: Oh good to know thanks! I am sure it is somewhere in the doc but I didn’t see it. However I suppose the best practice is to import it as a module right ?

Comment: Hum... You can still include links like this, that if you use external libraries. It could depend on different factors. 
But the way, `create-react-app` works, it bundles all your javascript into one single file, therefore for any code that you write, it is better to use as said in the other response `exports.helloWorld` or `export` from `ES6` [here is some useful example](https://hackernoon.com/import-export-default-require-commandjs-javascript-nodejs-es6-vs-cheatsheet-different-tutorial-example-5a321738b50f)

Answer (score 1):

If you check your Network tab in your debugger, it might actually *load* for you.  But you're not seeing the effect on your screen because that's not how create-react-app works.  It's not serving you a blank index page, it's set up to serve a div that it injects your React app into.  You're not finding this on the internet because it's just not how this tool works.  Read the docs and learn how it's intended to work and you'll be very happy you did. :)