# How to use clickWrap API inside a react SPA

Tags: reactjs, typescript, docusignapi, external-script, clickwrap

Need to add DocuSign clickwrap (https://developers.docusign.com/docs/click-api/how-to/embed-clickwraps/) inside a React SPA... the issue is that the modal which opens up is inconsistent...

checked this solution: [React with Docusign Clickwrap API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64128415/react-with-docusign-clickwrap-api)
the actual issue is that sometimes the modal pop-up, other times it doesn't... and at times that it doesn't show up, we get the 'onAgreed' callback triggered?

Had to use this because I am using TypeScript: [Property does not exist on type Window & typeof globalThis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66120513/property-does-not-exist-on-type-window-typeof-globalthis/67246476#67246476)

Also tried this: [React - issues with loading an external script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50519113/react-issues-with-loading-an-external-script)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for notifying us about this issue. Our developers are informed and currently working to deploy a fix. I will update you soon if a workaround is available

Comment: Hi Ivan, the issue is because I had already agreed to terms and condition for that particular user inside my React App... but having said this, the modal doesn't always render completely... you can check in the attached demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-docusign-clickwrap

Comment: Thank you for the code sample. I referred to the modal rendering issue. It is not React specific.